# Using COUNT and UNION to extract data and support a scenario

Tags: sql, count

I am dealing with a database with thousands of customers.

I am wanting to find groups of single customers who have exactly ONE qualifying discount voucher which is valid and exactly ONE non-qualifying voucher which is valid.

1. A qualifying voucher is one that has a minimum spend amount of £0.01 or more.
2. A non-qualifying voucher is one that does not have a minimum spend and is therefore £0.00
3. 'Valid' refers to the 'from' date being today or before and the 'to' date being today or in the future

I have initially set up the query below but all this is doing is searching for all customers who have valid qualifying AND non-qualifying voucherS. I am trying to find customers who have JUST ONE valid qualifying voucher and JUST ONE non-qualifying voucher:

```
select CustomerId, VoucherId, MinimumSpendAmount, ValidFromDate, ValidToDate
from dbo.discountvoucher
where ValidFromDate <= 15/11/2013
and ValidToDate >= 15/11/2013
order by CustomerId
```

I think I need to split this into 2 separate SELECT statements, one looking for single customers with 1 qualifying voucher (using COUNT), and one looking for single customers with 1 non-qualifying voucher (using COUNT). And then combining them with a UNION. But I could be totally wrong...

Please can anybody help

Comment: Have you tried to do the union?

Comment: A union wouldnt resolve the issue would it. I think it needs to do a COUNT as well where count = 1 but I am not sure how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub select with a GROUP BY and HAVING CLAUSE to find the customers that match your criteria.

```
select CustomerId, VoucherId, MinimumSpendAmount, ValidFromDate, ValidToDate
from dbo.discountvoucher
where ValidFromDate <= 15/11/2013
and ValidToDate >= 15/11/2013
and CustomerId in
    (select CustomerId
    from dbo.discountvoucher
    where ValidFromDate <= 15/11/2013
    and ValidToDate >= 15/11/2013
    group by CustomerId
    having sum(case when MinimumSpendAmount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and sum(case when MinimumSpendAmount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    )
order by CustomerId
```